# How can I trim an XML feed in XSL while preserving HTML tags?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an rss feed of news stories. I would like to display the headline and the first 350 characters of the story, with a link to the full story. However, if that 350th character is in the middle of an HTML tag (ie `<img ...` or even `<h2>`), my output HTML breaks and the link will not work. Here is my XSL

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
<xsl:for-each select="//rss/channel/item">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></h2><br />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(description, 1, 350)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
<a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="link" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">?tmpl=component&amp;print=1</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>Read more</a>
<br />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(pubDate,1,16)"/><br />
<br/>
<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

One note: I do not want to ignore HTML tags. If there is an image, I would like to include that.

I've found some similar questions answered here, but none of them have seemed to work for me. Thanks so much for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: possible duplicate of [trim mixed content to max number of characters with xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585133/trim-mixed-content-to-max-number-of-characters-with-xslt)

Comment: I tried your XSL on a feed from BBC news

(http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/news_front_page/rss.xml?edition=uk) 

It works fine, I think. Could it be that your links already contain a question mark, and then you'd have to change the question mark you're adding to a ampersand?

Comment: Yves B, it only happens rarely - if that 350th character happens to be in the middle of an HTML tag.
Dimitre Novatchev, I'll have a look at that, thanks.

Comment: Dimitre Novatchev, I don't see how I could apply that particular solution to my problem.

Comment: It's really difficult to know which of various diagnoses or solutions will work for you without seeing sample input. There are RSS standards, but not everybody follows them (see e.g. http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/CommentView.aspx?guid=71f25fd6-9b6f-4555-9940-3c339630a8d9).

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem seems to be that you're trying to take escaped HTML (which is not structured markup) and output it as structured markup (unescaped HTML).

Disable-output-escaping is a quick-and-dirty way to do this, not a robust way, as you can see: as soon as you try operations on the string (such as trimming), you lose well-formedness because you're not operating on a tree structure, you're operating on a string.

To do this properly, you'd need to actually parse the escaped HTML from the description element, so that you have it as a tree structure. Then you could use the solution @Dimitre pointed to.

How to parse the escaped HTML in the `<description>`? You could write a bunch of fancy XSLT to parse the string... that would be a headache, but doable. Or if you have Saxon available, you could use the [saxon:parse() extension function](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.4/extensions.html#parse). You might have to wrap element start/end tags around the string first, because saxon:parse() expects the string to be well-formed XML. E.g.

```
saxon:parse(concat('<p>', description, '</p>'))
```